# Multiplying all edge capacities by a positive number doesn't change the minimum cut

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Given is a graph defines a flow network. 
I need to formal proof the following :

> If we multiply all edge capacities by a positive number $X$, the minimum cut remains unchanged

Comment: Which cut? Please provide more details

Comment: Usually cuts can be defined as critical point of a Rayleigh quotient and multiplying the weight by a positive number will only increase its critical value but the critical points stays unchanged.

Comment: I mean that the same sets of vertices defined the minimum cut for maximum flow in the network will still be the same sets after multiplication

Comment: well... I'm not sure to know what is the "minimum cut for maximum flow"... Do you have a variational characterization of this cut?

Comment: The total capacity of each set of edges gets multiplied by the same positive number. Regardless of how you define the cut, "minimality" or "maximality" will not be changed.

Comment: @Surb, a minimum cuts created in a situation that no flow can pass from the source to the sink. then edges which we cant pass flow through them defines a min cut

Comment: @TheAlgoMan Are you talking about the max-flow and min-cut described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)?

Comment: @RandyE, yes exactly.

Comment: Okay. I don't have time for a full proof, but the key fact is that given a cut in the original graph, the capacity of the cut in the new graph is $X$ times the capacity in the original graph.  It follows that given two cuts, the inequality between their capacities in the new graph is the same as the inequality between the their capacities in the old graph.

Comment: @RandyE, thanks! i got to that fact too, but I can't see the full formal proof yet.

Comment: @RandyE Which inequalities do you mean?